# My footer moves down and then up when I click in my last list element...using slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list in my footer with some links, and when I click in my last list element "See more links" I replace my list to another with jQuery slideToggle().

But when I do this I see my footer bottom go a bit down and up again.

Do you know how can I fix this? I have my example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEBql

This is my jQuery:

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    $('#list1,#list2').slideToggle();
});;

$('#change_links1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#change_links2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Im getting this with your solution George:

[image]

I put background yellow in my #col div and blue is my #footer1.

Comment: I had to specify the jQuery library at codepen before it would work. Anyway good question.

Comment: Suggest that you also bring your html and part of your CSS into this question here, after all that's where the fix will have to be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big jolt comes from the native margin you have on your `<ul>`. If you remove that margin, the large jolt disappears:

**CSS**

```
#footer1 ul{
    margin:0;
    list-style:none; 
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/4ma6es6h/)

The tiny 1 pixel movement you see afterwards, comes from the slide animations not animating in synchronization.

You could 'fix' that, using jQuery, by setting the height of `#col` on page load:

**JavaScript**

```
$('#col').height(function(_,v){ return v; });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/4ma6es6h/1/)

Comment: Thank you George! Your solution works perfectly. Thanks also for your explanation!

Comment: George, I update my question with an image. With your solution I noticed now, that my "See more links" appears as a bit hidden. Do you see why this is happening?